# Thingworx sensor value to Sql Database

Tags: sql, database, thingworx

I am using Thingworx Platform for IoT. I have connected Thingworx and SQL. I have created 2 database SQL services of the type query and command. Also I have created two tables named `Temperature` and `Humidity`.

I am getting `Temperature` and `Humidity` values in Thingworx platform. But I am unable to send it to the database, can anyone help? How can I call the properties in the command service?

Database.Conf sql Command code

```
insert into INFO(Temperature)
values ([[]]);
```

Thing-Test Subscription Code

```js
var params={Temp:me.Temp_Prop,Hum:me.Hum_Prop};
var result=Things["DatabaseConf"].InsertRecords(params);
```

Comment: The values are automatically stored in the database in case you mark it as persistent.

Comment: A quick correction, only the last value of a property is stored in the database if you mark it as persistent. That is overwritten each time a new value arrives. Storing all the values is achieved by marking it as logged (and using a ValueStream)

Comment: For whoever wants to record property changes in the platform, I want to add that the platform offers a way to store Property values without writing any code, by using the Logged attribute for a property. I presume the question above has some specific requirements that do not allow using this capability.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a service in ThingWorx you can select the type: "query" is a valid option when you have to insert or retrieve values from a database. You can test the query on SQl and copy/paste into the service.
Check if the thing that connects you to the DataBase has the property "isConnected" equal to True.
Maybe you should also think about how to trigger the Insert service, you can use ValueChange triggers or a Periodic Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additionnal service of type javascript where you can retrieve the properties, using me.property and invoke the sql services. You can add input parameters to the sql services and use them like this: [[inputParameter]]. In your example that should look like:

```
insert into INFO(Temperature)
values ([[temp]],[[Hum]]);
```

If you use the arrow on the right of your input parameter, ThingWorx will write it for you in the proper way already.